# Find relative file path to MediaWiki image

Tags: javascript, json, mediawiki

BEFORE I START: I'M ONLY USING JAVASCRIPT

I try to find the relative image path used on this page (I want it to be dynamic per item name). I found this link http://2007.runescape.wikia.com/wiki/File:Abyssal_whip.png where the image is placed on the wikia. the only thing is I want this image found on the same link: [image]

When I click that image I come to this link: http://img2.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20130726060939/2007scape/images/5/5c/Abyssal_whip.png

Is there any way to retrieve this specific path by giving in this link?: http://2007.runescape.wikia.com/wiki/File:Abyssal_whip.png

I hope someone comes up with any ideas on how to achieve this, as I can't seem to find a proper way to fix this problem.

If you have any further questions on this please let me know.

EDIT: This did the job for me `http://2007.runescape.wikia.com/wiki/Special:Filepath/Abyssal_whip.png`

Result: [image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Method 1:**

There is a [magic word](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Magic_words) to get an absolute path to a file: `{{filepath}}`

In your case you would do:

```
{{filepath:Abyssal_whip.png}}
```

...or to get the path to a 300px wide thumbnail:

```
{{filepath:Abyssal_whip.png|200}}
```

This will give you a *protocol relative*, *absolute path* to the file (e.g. `//img2.wikia.nocookie.net/[…]/Abyssal_whip.png`).

There is no straightforward way to get the relative path to a file (and I really can't imagine why you would need that). You can parse the string, removing the first part, if the images are always at the same server (i.e. you are not using Wikimedia Commons or any other external image repositories. Not sure if Wikia has that enabled or not), using [Extension:ParserFunctions](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:ParserFunctions) (installed at Wikia). It would look something like this:

```
{{#replace:{{filepath:{{{image|}}}}}|//img2.wikia.nocookie.net/[…]|}}
```

**Method 2:**

There is a special page called `Special:Filepath`, that will give you the path to any file. Once again, you will only get the *absolute path*, so not really what you asked about. In your case [`http://2007.runescape.wikia.com/wiki/Special:Filepath/Abyssal_whip.png`](http://2007.runescape.wikia.com/wiki/Special:Filepath/Abyssal_whip.png) redirect to the actual file. You should be able to use this for links, or in scripts.

Comment: Does this work in JavaScript too? I'm not using PHP or something you know

EDIT: I'm loading data from the JSON formats so I don't need/want to use php

Comment: Oh, I though you wanted to do this on a wiki page. Are you asking about how to get the path of a file using the API?

Comment: I just want to retrieve the link to the nocookie page but without use of the API, well if the API is supporting javascript then yes I would like to use the API, not sure if javascript is supported

Comment: The API doesn't care (or even know) about what language you are using, it just returns the result. It can also return JSON. Anyway, I added a second method, that might be useful in yuor script, if you do not want to use the API.

Comment: This: http://2007.runescape.wikia.com/wiki/Special:Filepath/Abyssal_whip.png 

did the trick for me, as it just needs the name for the image, thanks! It did the job for me I think! =)

EDIT: It worked for some images, sometimes it returned wrong values, but that is not the problem I think =) I might figure out a way to work around this